# Converting .dwg to .shp using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, dwg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import DWG in QGIS project?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-import-dwg-in-qgis-project)

I have a .dwg file and I need to covert to shp file using QGIS. There is the dxf to shp plugin, but I need .dwg file to shp file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the conversion in two steps as QGIS cant do it in one. There is a converter available to convert .dwg to a .dxf file. It is from the Open Design Alliance. It is the Teigha file converter and available here: [Teigha file converter](http://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles//.)

Step two is to use The available plugin Dxf2shp converter to make the last step.