# Convert DWG to SHP in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dxf, dwg

Given files by client:

.dwg
.bak

QGIS doesn't like it; FREECAD doesn't like it; RhinoCAD doesn't like it  or Illustrator.

QGIS > Project > Import as .dwg/.dxf actually asks for .gdb, which doesn't help.

Found previous answer here: [Converting .dwg to .shp using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44948/converting-dwg-to-shp-using-qgis)

but it's not complete and from 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Convert from DWG to DXF to SHP:

1. Download and open ODA File converter: https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles
2. Convert DWG to DXF (Choose lastest year - mine was 2018 - ASCII DXF)
3. Use QGIS Plugin 'Another DXF Import/Converter' to add from folder to 
   new folder (Don't forget to click 'Save as shapefiles')
4. Loads in QGIS in layers

2020/01/19

Comment: Direct link for download software: https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter