# Opening DWG file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dwg

I am working on a landscape design in QGIS and I was sent an old DWG file with contour lines that I would like to use in QGIS. I would like to import the controur lines, but I am having issues.

When I try to import the DWG file into QGIS as a layer, it starts loading objects from the DWG file, but then i get this error in red:

**Drawing import failed (error in entities read process.)**

I can see the names of the layers in the DWG import tool, but the no matter what i select the OK button remains disabled.

What could be the reason? I suspect it might either have to do with the fact that I dont have a clue what CRS was used in the DWG file, nor do I know how to check this..

Another doubt I have is that the DWG file also refers to an ortofoto.jpg file.. COuld this be the issue?

I do not have Autocad software, but I was able to open the DWG file with Autodesk Trueview and also I was able to save it as a DWG 2013 file.

UPDATE:

I was able to open the DWG file with this workaround: [Convert DWG to SHP in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347923/convert-dwg-to-shp-in-qgis)

However, it turns out the location is not correct.. I tried several different CRS, but in the best match its still off by around 100 km.. Moving is pointless as it turns out the scale is also off for that CRS..
Is there still hope to use this data?

Comment: Try to save the DWG file in an older version something like version 14 and try again.

Comment: Also you can try to export your DWG to DXF format and import it in QGIS

Comment: Can you post your drawing? Maybe a WeTransfer link?

Comment: Ok I was able to open the data using these instructions:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347923/convert-dwg-to-shp-in-qgis

However it seems, that the CRS is not correct. I tried all the the plausible ones for my area, but no luck. I am starting to think, that the architect never had any CRS defined.. there are buildings on the map, so i should be able to overlay it on the right location. but not sure how to move the polygons to the right coordinates..

Comment: Well, I was able to select and move the contour line features, but when I manage to get to my right location it turns out that the scale is off by a factor of 2 or so.. so no point in just manually moving the contour lines to the right location..

Comment: The Plugin AnotherDXFImporter contains a module for georeferencing https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355220/re-scaling-and-moving-vector-layer-manually-in-qgis/355257#355257

Comment: @mike Ok thanks, I am gonna try with this plugin.