# DWG to shapefile?

Tags: autocad

How to convert AutoCAD (DWG) file to shapefile (SHP)?
if I check in the export option, there is no option for converting the acad file shape,
what is the use of converting the data to shape?

Comment: Have you tried using QGIS? This question has info on turning the DWG into a DXF which QGIS can open: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-import-a-dwg-into-a-qgis-project

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, none of which are perfect... However, [FME](http://www.safe.com/) is a good way to go if you have a license. Alternatively, use `MAPEXPORT` command in Civil3D/Map to export to shape (one feature type at a time). There are also, as others have mentioned, functions in both QGIS and ArcMap to deal with dwg files.

Answer (score -1):

You could try Spatial Manager for AutoCAD:
http://www.spatialmanager.com/spm-forautocad/

You can also download the trial versión from Autodesk Exchange: https://apps.autodesk.com/ACD/es/Detail/Index?id=appstore.exchange.autodesk.com%3aspatialmanagerforautocad_windows32and64%3aen

Comment: Do not use shortened url's in you answer, these urls hide the place where you redirect to.