# Convert AutoCAd file (.dwg) to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, cad, dwg

I have a CAD file to convert into shapefile. Unfortunately, I don't have access to AutoCAD, MapInfo or ArcGIS atm. All I have access to is QGIS.

I'll need to convert this CAD file to shapefile to be used in a specialised software which can use/edit shapefile.

I tried couple of online tools without any success. Any help? BTW the size of the CAD file is less than 2MB.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Have you tried opening the DWG in QGIS?  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/importing-dwg-into-qgis-project