# Import of DWG into QGIS is very slow. Is my computer the problem?

Tags: qgis, import, dwg

I'm working on some projects that have CAD data as the basis which I import into QGIS. For the last project, this has taken over 36h.

Is my computer too slow and, if so, which part (RAM or processor)?

I'm using a:

HP Z440 Xeon E5-1650 v4 Hexa Core

3.6GHx WIN 10

32GB RAM

512 SSD

8GB NVidia Quadro M4000

2TB HDD SATA III

I'm running QGIS 3.16.5.
The DWG has a size of 25MB, I do not use curves. Everything is stored on the SSD. The HDD is my backup.
I've attached a screenshot of the task manager when I'm importing the data.
[image: Processes]

[image: RAM]

Comment: How many layers are in the CAD? Hashes, blocks, references? Which spatial extent are we talking about?

Comment: try DWG to Geopackage https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265968/276

Comment: This is what I'm doing Mapperz. I cannot access the CAD data directly but the last project resulted in about 96 layers, some with millions of attributes.

Comment: try DXF with the plugin AnotherDXFImporter https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/